# Flex - How to override the result event (HTTPService)?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a global settings class, and i want to switch a var (to 1) in this class, when i call the send function and switch this var (to 0), when the result event dispatched.

I created a class, extends HTTPService..i can override the send function (override public function send(parameters:Object=null):AsyncToken), but how can i override the function, which call when the result arrived?

Thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: When the result arrives; an event is dispatched.  You really want to listen to this event and perform your own logic; not extend the class and change the way it announces it received a result.  @Constantiner has the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use events but not to extend `HTTPService`. So if you read [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html) you can see three events which solves your problem: `invoke`, `result` and `fault`. Just subscribe to them.

Comment: Yes, i know, that your advice is solves my problem.
But i have a lot of HTTPService in many classes, and i don't want to subscribe to all result these..
So..at any time when i use HTTPService, i want to switch this var (send-1, result-1), so i want to override these functions once, because thus i saving up many code lines..

Comment: +1 as if I understand what the user wants to do; this seems like a significantly better approach than his "extend and change" approach.

Comment: @johnyFlex Use the same listener for all the HTTPService result calls and you'll have the same benefit of only having to change it in one place.

Comment: @johnyflex You can create some service class and use `HTTPService` in it as composition. This class will subscribe `HTTPService` instance events and perform your logic. Inheritance isn't the only solution for all the problems. Composition can be useful too.

Comment: Johny, you might also want to look at the command and delegate patterns.  The delegate abstracts your service layer (HTTPService) and the command abstracts the call/result.  Most frameworks use this pattern.

Comment: Thank you to all for the helps, the composition solved my problem.